# android AndEngine get Tap(Click) events?

Tags: android, opengl-es, tap, andengine

i am using AndEngine and to get touch events.
there is OnAreaTouched() event,

but i need to get TAP event of images drawn (to Click)..i can do that using onAreaTouch but that gives even when user simply touch..i want user to tap on that.  Suggestions, examples, or tutorials?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by tap? A click?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, a click is a combination of `ACTION_DOWN`, some `ACTION_MOVE`'s and an `ACTION_UP` touch event actions, that appear in a small area. All you need to do is to check, whether your `ACTION_UP` appeared near to your `ACTION_DOWN`. If you need some extra accuracy, you can check the time interval between those actions to be sure this was a click. Just store position and time of the `ACTION_DOWN` and compare it to your `ACTION_UP`'s position and time - and you'll be able to differentiate click from fling or something else. Hope this helps.